# How do I prevent user from typing specific characters from the keyboard in android studio?

Tags: java, android, keyboard

for example, when user touches the characters on the keyboard (a to z) nothing is typed in the Edit Text (Even though it's focused), but when he touches any of the numbers it IS typed in the Edit text.
I don't want to change the keyboard itself(or create a custom keyboard) I just want to filter some of the characters.
How do I do it?
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Thanks for the question, this helped me out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will allow users to type only small letters of alphabets you can add digits and special characters too.

```
<Edittext android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"/>
```

Comment: awesome and easy, thanks. if I want to use Upper case letters should I include them as well?

Comment: yes sir! you can use any letters,digits or special characters

Answer (score 5):

in EditText xml:

```
android:digits="1234567890"
```

this will allow only numbers